# ¿Cómo cargar un select con datos específicos de dos consultas?

Tags: php, html5

En un formulario el cual lo estoy haciendo para editar los datos, estoy realizando una consulta y obtengo los datos de un item utilizando un where

```
$query = "SELECT prod.descripcion_producto, prod.precio, prod.disponible, prod.path_foto, prod.destacado, prod.nuevo, cat.descripcion_categoria, prod.id_categoria, subcat.descripcion_subcategoria, prod.id_subcategoria
                  FROM producto AS prod
                  INNER JOIN categoria AS cat
                    ON prod.id_categoria = cat.id_categoria
                  INNER JOIN subcategoria AS subcat
                    ON prod.id_subcategoria = subcat.id_subcategoria
                  WHERE prod.id_producto = '$id'";
```

Los datos que utilizo para poner en un select son `id_categoria` y `descripcion_categoria`
los cuales son guardados en variables para despues especificarlos en el `<option>` y en el html tengo lo siguiente:

```
<tr>
     <td class="descripcion"><label for="categoria"><strong>Categoría</strong></label></td>
     <td class="cajaTxt">
         <select id="categoria" name="categoria">
             <option value="<?php echo $idCat.','.$nomCat; ?>" ><?php echo $nomCat; ?></option>
         </select>
     </td>
</tr>
```

En otro formulario el cual es de creación lo cargo de la siguiente manera:

```
<select id="categoria" name="categoria">
    <?php
    $query1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id_categoria, descripcion_categoria FROM categoria WHERE habilitado = '1'");
    while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
        //echo $cat;
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cat['id_categoria'].','.$cat['descripcion_categoria'] ?>" ><?php echo $cat['descripcion_categoria'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

En sí, mi idea como estoy en el formulario en el que edito los valores es la de mostrar los datos que han sido guardados previamente, sin embargo, me gustaría cargar también todos los datos que se obtiene en la tabla categoría.

**¿De que manera puedo hacer que se carguen todos los datos pero que primero se muestre los datos que pertenecen al item que ha sido seleccionado?**

Comment: ¿Has hecho un `mysqli_query()` con su `mysqli_fetch_array` para el primer `select/option`?

Comment: Si @David JP, en el primer query solo obtengo el código de la categoría de ese item y mediante el join obtengo la descripción o nombre de esa categoría y en sí solo estoy usando un ``select/option``

Comment: Entonces, ya tienes todo, ¿no?

Comment: Los datos ya los tengo, solo que no tengo idea de como cargar el ``select`` y que me aparezca primero el ``option`` que sea igual al del que obtengo por la primera consulta; ejemplo por decir tengo 10 opciones de categoría y la que tiene el item especifico por decirte es hogar y me gustaría que se cargaran todas las opciones pero que a la vez se muestre como valor inicial del ``option`` la mencionada anteriormente.

Comment: La parte de la interfaz es la que me falta encontrar un método para alcanzar el objetivo

Comment: Creo que te refieres al uso de la etiqueta `<form method="post">` y al uso de las superglobales `$_POST['categoria']` para que en el backend puedas procesar la elección que hayas hecho... Si es así, investiga un poco en esta línea y concreta tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte